# Cohen-Macaulay/Gorenstein passing from associated graded to general fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a filtered commutative ring over a field $k$. Let $A$ denote the Rees algebra and $A_0:=\operatorname{gr}_F(R)$ be the associated graded ring.  $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ gives rise to a flat family over $\mathbb{A}^1$ with fiber over zero $\operatorname{Spec}(A_0)$ and general fiber $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Assume that $A$(and hence $R$ and $A_0$) is finitely generated.

Question 1) Is it true that $\operatorname{Spec}(A_0)$ being Cohen-Macaulay implies that $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Question 2) Is there a nice condition for when $A_0$ being Gorenstein implies that $R$ is Gorenstein? How about in the case when the filtration is associated to some ideal I?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Call the total space of the family $X$ and let $X_0=\operatorname{Spec} R_0$. Let $x\in X_0$ and let $t$ be the coordinate on $\mathbb{A}^1$. Consider the exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{O}_X\stackrel{t}{\to} \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_{X_0}\to 0$. Taking stalks at $x$, we get that $0\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}\stackrel{t}{\to} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X_0,x}\to 0$ is exact, ie $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/t\cong \mathcal{O}_{X_0,x}$, so a regular sequence in $\mathcal{O}_{X_0,x}$ gives rise to a regular sequence in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ by appending $t$. (More generally, this strategy works for any surjective flat morphism of schemes $f:X\to Y$. $X$ is CM iff $Y$ is CM and each fiber $X_y$ is CM). This shows that every point in $X_0$ considered as a point of $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, and since Cohen-Macaulayness is an open condition, there exists an open set $U$ containing $X_0$ such that $U$ is Cohen-Macaulay. But by the dilation action coming from $\mathbb{A}^1$, we know that $U$ is in fact the whole space.
2. Yes, via a similar strategy to the last time. In full generality, let $f:X\to Y$ be a flat surjective morphism of schemes. $X$ Gorenstein is equivalent to $Y$ Gorenstein and $X_y$ Gorenstein for all $y\in Y$. See for instance http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250523903 theorem 1. Apply with $X$ same as in 1 and $Y=\mathbb{A}^1$ to get that each point of $X_0$ considered as a point in $X$ is Gorenstein, combine with Gorenstein being an open condition, and the same reasoning about the dilation action.

Comment: I like this idea...but is it completely obvious that when you dilate U you get all of X? Geometrically it seems like the assertion is something like U must contain an entire fiber $X_y$ for some $y \neq 0$?

Comment: For example if we take k[x] with the trivial filtration by degree, Let the total space be Spec(k[x,t]). Then U could be the complement of some xt=c?

Comment: The assertion is not that $U$ must contain an entire fiber $X_y$ but that the intersection of $U$ with any horizontal fiber is non-empty and open (thus it contains a non-zero point) and the map $\phi: X\to \mathbb{A}^1$ is $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant, so that upon restriction to any horizontal fiber any two non-zero points look the same via the dilation action.

Comment: I think I understand... Could we say that any $\mathbb{G}_m$ orbit in $X$ has a limit point in the zero fiber... therefore the complement $Z$ of $U$ also being $\mathbb{G}_m$ equivariant must contain a point in the zero fiber and hence be empty?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: While this answer clarifies the geometric features of the problem, I think it is for the moment not correct. The issue of the G_m orbit having a limit point is more subtle--- see Remark 3.6 of  https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250521977 for a counterexample to the claim in full generality. In fact for filtrations coming from ideals the result can only be proven under strong hypotheses see the above paper or the older https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102948658. Perhaps it is always true for nonnegative ascending filtrations i.e. when F_n=0 for n<0?

Comment: I don't see a remark 3.6 in the linked paper - are you sure about what you're referencing? It might also be a good idea to hammer out our definitions of the Rees algebra, since perhaps a definitional mismatch might be hurting us - for me, the Rees algebra of an algebra $A$ with filtration $F^iA$ is the graded algebra $\mathrm{Rees}(A):=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} t^nF^nA$, and $\mathrm{Spec}\mathrm{Rees}(A)$ is well-behaved as long as $\mathrm{Rees}(A)$ is fg and unital. Do these match your definitions? Do you explicitly care about non-unital or non-fg situations?

Comment: Same definitions and don't care about cases when Rees is not fg (for me Rees is always unital) --- I meant remark 3.5 and example 3.6. of the paper.

Comment: I think because in general the G_m action on the Rees algebra will have positive and negative weights, some G_m orbits will escape to infinity and not have limit points in the central fiber. If the filtration is nonpositive (or nonnegative depending on convention) then this wont happen and your proof works.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this answer is to provide certain clarifications to KReiser's answer

1. In general, it is not true that the general fiber must be Cohen Macaulay see Example 3.6 of https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250521977
   for an example where $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$, the filtration is associated to the maximal ideal $(x,1-y)$, and $A_0=k[y]$.
2. In order to deduce the CM property or Gorenstein property of the special fiber using the approach outlined in KReiser's answer (or in commutative algebra terms the approach of the above article) one needs that every $\mathbb{G}_m$ orbit has a limit point in the special fiber.

The easiest situation to do this is when the descending filtration lives in nonpositive degrees and $F_0=k\cdot 1$. In the case of filtrations associated to an ideal $I$(the setting of the aforementioned article), this is rather rare and requires that $I$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$.